# Inexplicable space between two divs

Tags: css, html

The problem is a space between the 4th and the 5th divs, which can be seen here:
 [JSFiddle.1](http://jsfiddle.net/Sm2xs/)

This space disappears if I combine the 1st and the last divs:
 [JSFiddle.2](http://jsfiddle.net/MHQGj/)

What can be a cause of this behavior?

**UPDATE:**
[image: this]
That how it *should* be look like.

Comment: One of your fiddles uses `display: block`, while the other uses `display: inline-block`. These two are not equivalent...

Comment: Also, dear Lord: *please* indent your HTML...

Comment: I think the issue is on display: inline-block in style="background-color: #4cff00; width:25%; margin:0 auto; display:inline-block;"

Comment: I've changed them all to inline-blocks but got another one space - between 1st and the 2nd line of divs.

Comment: This is a mess. What are you trying to achieve? How exactly should the outcome look?

Comment: I don't understand. The image you've added has more elements than the markup you provided. Is there supposed to be some fixed-width `position: absolute;` tomfoolery going on here?

Comment: Screen shot is my aim that I has drawn in paint.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please, for the love of The Flying Spaghetti Monster, *format your code properly!*

In any case, the reason your `inline-block`s aren't working is because you didn't set `font-size: 0;` on their container.

[Here's your updated jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/jezen/Sm2xs/3/)

And here's a much prettier version of your code:

**HTML**

```
<div id="listLeft">
    <div id="Left" class="pluginAdd">
        <p>left</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="listMiddle">
    <div id="Middle" class="pluginAdd">
        <p>middle</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="listRight">
    <div id="Right" class="pluginAdd">
        <p>right</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="listBottom">
    <div id="Bottom" class="pluginAdd">
    </div>
</div>
​
```

**CSS**

```
body {font-size: 0;}

.pluginAdd {
    background-color: #ffd800;
    width: 70px;
    height: 15px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
    font-size: 12px;
    background: url('/Images/pluginAdd.png') no-repeat center;
} 

#listTop {background: #b6ff00; width:100%; margin:0 auto; display:block;}
#listLeft {background: #4cff00; width:25%;  margin:0 auto; display:inline-block;}
#listMiddle {background: #00ff21; width:50%;  margin:0 auto; display:inline-block;}
#listRight {background: #00ff90; width:25%;  margin:0 auto; display:inline-block;}
#listBottom {background-color: #0ff; width:100%; margin:0 auto; display:block;}
​
```

Comment: Wow, it's really works. Much thanks, this question stopped my work for half of my working day.

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by the `line-height` being greater than the height of the `inline-block` elements.

To fix, set `line-height:1px` on the container of the elements. If you have text in those elements, you'll probably need to add `line-height: 1.2em` (the default) on the elements themselves.

Comment: Should this css be appended only to the last div-container style or for all containers'?

Comment: For all containers would be easiest, but in theory just the `inline-block` ones.

Comment: A tried to add this style to last block, to all the top-level blocks and to only ones which have inline-block as display-property value. But it hasn't make any effect(